# Matlab not taking last number in array?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I've got a `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch` problem.

I've already localized the issue, and know exactly what is going on, I just don't know why.

Here's the problematic piece of code:

```
mFrames(:,i) = vSignal(round(start:1:frameLength*samplingRate));
start=start+frameShift*samplingRate; 
frameLength = frameLength+frameShift;
```

I've already checked what's going on in debugmode; usually my resulting column length of `mFrames` is `128`, this stays the same until `i=1004`. Then, my column length changes to `127`.

I've checked the values involved while in debug mode, and it simply does not make sense what is going on. At `i==1004` `start=32097` and `frameLength*samplingRate=32224`.
That's a difference of `127` meaning `128` points, that should work.

BUT when i assign a vector `A=round(start:1:frameLength*samplingRate)`

OR `B=start:1:frameLength*samplingRate`

In both cases I get a vector going from `32097` to `32223`. This ALTHOUGH when I give in `frameLength*samplingRate` matlab is giving me `32224`.

In other words, matlab is telling me it's using one number, but when I test I find it's using a different one.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: am i getting downvoted because i included so little code?

Comment: im not looking for a complete solution, all i need is a pointer what could be causing in this to happen

Comment: why do you use round()? The downvote might be because you didn't provide a working example or a way to reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your `32224` is not actually `32224`. MATLAB's default format only displays so many decimal places, so when dealing with floating point numbers, what is printed on screen is not necessarily the "exact" value.

Let's go back a step and look at how the synatx `x = start:step:end` works.

`1:1:10` should give us numbers in steps of 1 from 1 to 10. Fair enough, that makes sense.  What if we set the end value to something that's slightly above 10?

e.g.:

`1:1:10.1`

Well, it still gives us `1:1:10`, (or `1:10`, 1 being the default step) because we can't have values higher than the end-point, so `11` isn't a correct step.

So what about this:

`1:1:9.99`

Spoiler: it's the same as `1:9`

And this?

```
 1:1:9.9999999
```

Yep, still `1:9`

But if we do this:

```
a = 9.9999999;
```

Then with default format, the value of `a` will be shown on the command line and in your list of workspace variables as 10.0000.

Now, if `frameLength` and `samplingRate` are both stored as floating point numbers, it's possible that the number you see as `32224` is not `32224` but very slightly below that. You can check this by changing your default format - e.g. `format long` at the command line - to show more decimal places.

The simplest solution is probably to do something like:

```
B=start:1:round(frameLength*samplingRate)
```

Or try to store the relevant values as integers (e.g., `uint32`).

Comment: thanks, someone else pointed this out to me beforehand and it's the right answer, works now!